# How can I pass argument as part of selenium webdriver command

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have below similar codes. The only difference is the browser I choose. I want to combine the duplicated codes into a function.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.ca')
driver.quit()

driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver2.get('http://www.google.com')
time.sleep(2)
driver2.quit()
```

I wrote the below function but seems cannot pass the browser_name as part of the command. Any solution for this?

```
def go_to_baidu(browser_name):
    driver = webdriver.browser_name()
    driver.get('http://www.baidu.com')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a value like `"Chrome"` or `"Firefox"` to your function, pass `webdriver.Chrome` or `webdriver.Firefox()` (without the quotes) instead. The, change the first line of the function like so:

```
def go_to_baidu(browser_name):
    driver = browser_name()
    driver.get('http://www.baidu.com')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()
```

You then run it like this:

```
go_to_baidu(webdriver.Chrome)
```

for example.

Functions are objects in Python, and can be passed to other functions just as easily as strings, lists, dicts, etc. can.